# Prob. 6, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: For $f$ continuous for $x\geq 0$ and differentiable for $x>0$ with $f(0)=0$, if $f^\prime$ is ...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Here is Prob. 6, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose
>
> (a) $f$ is continuous for $x \geq 0$,
>
> (b) $f^\prime(x)$ exists for $x>0$,
>
> (c) $f(0)=0$,
>
> (d) $f^\prime$ is monotonically increasing.
>
> Put $$ g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x} \qquad  ( x>0)$$ and prove that $g$ is monotonically increasing.

My Attempt:

> For any $x>0$, as $f$ is continuous on $[0, x]$ and differentiable on $(0, x)$, so by the Mean Value Theorem there is a point $p \in (0, x)$ such that
> $$ f(x) = f(x) - 0 = f(x)-f(0) = (x-0) f^\prime(p) = x f^\prime(p).$$
> But as $f^\prime$ is monotonically increasing on $(0, +\infty)$ and as $0 < p < x$, so we can conclude that $f^\prime(p) \leq f^\prime(x)$ and hence
> $$f(x) = xf^\prime(p) \leq x f^\prime(x),$$
> which implies that $$x f^\prime(x) - f(x) \geq 0 \ \mbox{ for all } \ x > 0.$$
> Now we see that, for any $x > 0$,
> $$ g^\prime(x) = \frac{f^\prime(x)}{x} - \frac{f(x)}{x^2} =  \frac{ xf^\prime(x) - f(x)}{x^2} \geq 0,$$
> which implies that $g$ is monotonically increasing on $(0, +\infty)$.

Is the above proof correct?

Comment: Yes, that all looks fine.